# How to force Jackson (with Spring) to include FetchType.LAZY field if it is annotated with @JsonView?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jackson, spring-restcontroller

If I have a class like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "game")
public class Game {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "player_id")
    @JsonView(AdminView.View.class)
    private Player player;

    //other fields

}
```

How do I force Spring and Jackson to fetch all the fields (and only those fields) that are annotated with both `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` and `@JsonView(AdminView.View.class)` before serializing JSON back to the client, if the client hit the `@GetMapping` controller which is also marked with the `@JsonView(AdminView.View.class)` annotation?

I dont want to use `Hibernate5Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING` because that will just force the loading of every lazy field on every request, even if it does not belong to a corresponding `@JsonView`. Can I make that force loading smarter, to just force load fields that are annotated with a matching `@JsonView`?

Comment: did you find an answer for this problem